# How to use IP Camera on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ip-camera

I want to see the IP Camera and encoding ,streamming  on Android

I found the 3 options

1. Use ffmpeg
2. Use OpenCV
3. Use WebView, VideoView

I tried to option 1
but I just can see the video in SD CARD 
--enable-network makes error

so I will try to option 2
Is it possible to work what I want?

Does anyone tell me the advice?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many information missing in your posting. So I try to guess: IP camera means you can access them via TCP/IP (may be HTTP?). So you do not need one of these huge packages that provide much more features than only image retrieval. You just have to open a connectiuon to your camera and pick up the image(s) it provides. Means you have to find out which communication protocol and image/video formats the camera provides.

Comment: I can access to IP camera by (HTTP or RTSP) then I can see the video from vlc player so I tried to use ffmpeg for encoding and streaming but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277356/to-see-ip-camera-using-ffmpeg

Comment: I just can see the video file in SD CARD

Comment: anyway I just want to know how to encoe and to stream the Video from the IP Camera